# What's the difference between read, readsome, get, and getline?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between these functions. When I use them they all do the same thing. For example all three calls return `"hello"`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    stringstream ss("hello");
    char x[10] = {0};
    ss.read(x, sizeof(x));          // #1
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    ss.clear();
    ss.seekg(0, ss.beg);
    ss.readsome(x, sizeof(x));      // #2
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    ss.clear();
    ss.seekg(0, ss.beg);
    ss.get(x, sizeof(x));           // #3
    std::cout << x;
    ss.clear();
    ss.seekg(0, ss.beg);
    ss.getline(x, sizeof(x));       // #4
    std::cout << x << std:endl;
}
```

Comment: read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)

Comment: @BryanChen I have, but I still don't understand the differences.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`get` and `getline` are quite similar, when `get` is called with parameters `( char_type* s, std::streamsize count )`. However, `get` reads from the stream until a delimiter is found, and then *leaves it there*. `getline` by comparison will pull the delimiter off the stream, but then drop it. It won't be added to the buffer it fills.

`get` looks for `\n`, and when a specific number of characters is provided in an argument (say, `count`) it will read up to `count - 1` characters before stopping. `read` will pull in all `count` of them.

You could envisage `read` as being an appropriate action on a binary datasource, reading a specific number of bytes. `get` would be more appropriate on a text stream, when you're reading into a string that you'd like null-terminated, and where things like newlines have useful syntactic meanings splitting up text.

`readsome` only returns characters that are immediately available in the underlying buffer, something which is a bit nebulous and implementation specific. This probably includes characters returned to the stream using `putback`, for example. The fact that you can't see the difference between `read` and `readsome` just shows that the two might share an implementation on the particular stream type and library you are using.

Answer (score 15):

I've observed the difference between `read()` and `readsome()` on a flash filing system.

The underlying stream reads 8k blocks and the `read` method will go for the next block to satisfy the caller, whereas the `readsome` method is allowed to return less than the request in order to avoid spending time fetching the next block.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between get() and getline() is that get() leaves the newline character in the input stream, making it the first character seen by the next input operation, whereas getline() extracts and discards the newline character from the input stream.